Dropping rows of a dataframe where selected columns has na values
I have below code
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    age=[5, 6, np.nan],
    born=[pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp('1939-05-27'), pd.Timestamp('1940-04-25')],
    name=['Alfred', 'Batman', np.nan],
    toy=[np.nan, 'Batmobile', 'Joker']))

Now I want to drop those rows where columns name OR toy have NaN/empty string values. I tried with below code
df[~df[['name', 'toy']].isna()]

I was expecting only 2nd row would return. Could you please help where I went wrong?

what is wrong
df[~df[['name', 'toy']].isna()] returns a DataFrame (2D), thus you will apply a mask on the whole DataFrame, keeping values that are truthy (the shape remains unchanged).
You're essentially doing:
df.where(~df[['name', 'toy']].isna())

Which will mask the non target columns with NaN and the NaN values from name/toy with NaN (= no change)
how to fix it
What you want to do is boolean indexing, you must pass a Series (and thus aggregate with any). Also, since '' is not considered a NaN, you first have to replace them to None:
out = df[~df[['name', 'toy']].replace('', None).isna().any(axis=1)]

Note that this is equivalent to using notna+all without the ~:
out = df[df[['name', 'toy']].replace('', None).notna().all(axis=1)]

Output:
   age       born    name        toy
1  6.0 1939-05-27  Batman  Batmobile


I am expecting only 2nd row as output, because only that row has elements with not nan

@Bogaso then you meant "Name OR toy", not "Name AND toy", note that it doesn't change the explanation. I'll update.

My choice is "Name OR toy"

See update, note that you also have to replace the empty strings

@Bogaso I realize that the current example is not the same as I initially copied, (my copy had an empty string). Had you edited it? If you're sure that you don't have empty strings, then df.dropna(subset = ['name' , 'toy']) is indeed enough as it was also suggested.
